# Importing Python Array to Javascript using Flask

Tags: javascript, python, html, arrays, null

I want to import a very big array from python to HTML

What I am doing Right now is

Python :

```
@app.route("/")
def Home():
    return render_template("PyHTML.html",XV=XV,Time=Time)
```

And in HTML

```
var XV = ['{{XV[0]}}','{{XV[1]}}','{{XV[2]}}','{{XV[3]}}','{{XV[4]}}']
var Time = ['{{Time[0]}}','{{Time[1]}}','{{Time[2]}}','{{Time[3]}}','{{Time[4]}}']
```

What can be done for large dataset of XV and Time?

Comment: Do you mean in Javascript?  That certainly doesn't look like HTML.  Also, if your data needs to go from the Python program to your HTML template, why isn't the data starting in your Python program?

Comment: Hey @coralv Thanks for Correction..

Comment: I am making graphs from that data in HTML